# Why my d3 graph still feel sluggish after the render has been done

Tags: d3.js, optimization

I created an hierarchical edge bundling diagram just like the example here

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1044242

The only difference is that it used quite big dataset and set svg container to be able for dragging and zooming. To my understanding, the drawing is only done once. Then why after that ,the movement when draging the svg around still somehow sluggish/slow (actually the whole application slowed down)?

Comment: Well when you drag (I assume you've implemented [d3.drag](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag/blob/master/README.md#drag)), you are changing the positions of all those SVG elements and yes this means the browswer has to redraw them...

Comment: Is there a way to avoid it?